# Python np.dstack : too many values to unpack

Tags: python, numpy

Was experimenting with np.dstack and got the error:

> ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)

Here's the code:

```
a = np.array((1,2,3))
b = np.array((2,3,4))
for x, y in np.dstack((a,b)):
    print(x,",",y)
```

solutions?

Comment: You might not be getting what you think you are. According to [https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.dstack.html] (numpy.dstack), it returns an array of arrays nested. Try iterating over `for x in np.dstack...` to check what you really have and how to iterate it properly.

Comment: Usually when people use `dstack` and other `concatenate` functions, they seek to use the whole array. Iterating over it isn't that useful.  An iteration like `for x, y in zip(a,b):` is common.

Answer (score 1):

In your case, the depth-wise stack result is

```
np.dstack((a,b))=
array([[[1, 2],
        [2, 3],
        [3, 4]]])
```

the result is an array of shape (1,3,2). Therefore when you iterate over this array, you are assigning an object of length 3 to a tuple of length 2, so you got that ValueError.

Depends on what you want, you can either

```
for x, y in np.dstack((a,b))[0]:
    print(x,",",y)
```

or

```
for x, y, z in np.dstack((a,b)):
    print(x,",",y)
```

Answer (score 0):

[dstack](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.12.0/reference/generated/numpy.dstack.html) returns a 3D array, so you need to iterate over the first index of the array:

```
for x, y in np.dstack((a,b))[0]:
    print(x,",",y)
```

You could also use [stack](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.12.0/reference/generated/numpy.stack.html):

```
for x, y in np.stack((a,b), axis=1):
    print(x,",",y)
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what you want to do.

A logical iteration using 2 arrays like this is:

```
In [290]: a = np.array((1,2,3))
     ...: b = np.array((2,3,4))
     ...: 
     ...: 
In [291]: for x,y in zip(a,b):print(x,y)
1 2
2 3
3 4
```

Or simply using the list `zip` method of 'transposing':

```
In [292]: list(zip(a,b))
Out[292]: [(1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 4)]
```

`dstack` combines the 2 array on a new 3rd axis, producing a 3d array:

```
In [293]: np.dstack((a,b))
Out[293]: 
array([[[1, 2],
        [2, 3],
        [3, 4]]])
In [294]: _.shape
Out[294]: (1, 3, 2)
```

Iterating on that doesn't make much sense.